# Java server to handle Client requests and respond to it?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, cloud

Im looking for the concept of creating Java Server to handle Client requests and respond to it , i want to use Google App engine which does not allow Socket connections , so is the client & server in this case will communicate using Http requests? i'll be glad if someone could clarify the logic to me and provide a few lines of code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers but i needed a simple methods to use it in Android App Like the following code :

**HTTP GET**

`

```
try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        String getURL = "http://www.google.com";
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
        HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
        HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();  
        if (resEntityGet != null) {  
                    //do something with the response
                    Log.i("GET RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet));
                }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}`
```

**HTTP POST**

```
try {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
    String postURL = "http://somepostaddress.com";
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL); 
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "kris"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "xyz"));
        UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
        post.setEntity(ent);
        HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  
        HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();  
        if (resEntity != null) {    
            Log.i("RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
        }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The code is from [this site](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-get-post-and-multipart-post-requests/) and you dont need any additional Jar files to use it in Android and i manged to use it with Google App engine.

Comment: This does not create a server...?

Answer (score 1):

[The Simple Framework](http://www.simpleframework.org/) may offer what you're looking for. It allows you to embed an HTTP server into your app with relatively little overhead:

```
import org.simpleframework.http.core.Container;
import org.simpleframework.transport.connect.Connection;
import org.simpleframework.transport.connect.SocketConnection;
import org.simpleframework.http.Response;
import org.simpleframework.http.Request;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class HelloWorld implements Container {

   public void handle(Request request, Response response) {
      PrintStream body = response.getPrintStream();
      long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

      response.set("Content-Type", "text/plain");
      response.set("Server", "HelloWorld/1.0 (Simple 4.0)");
      response.setDate("Date", time);
      response.setDate("Last-Modified", time);

      body.println("Hello World");
      body.close();
   } 

   public static void main(String[] list) throws Exception {
      Container container = new HelloWorld();
      Connection connection = new SocketConnection(container);
      SocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(8080);

      connection.connect(address);
   }
}
```

To compare with other solutions, note that Simple is not only embeddable, but open source, fully self-contained and asynchronous throughout. Good luck!

Comment: Can you explain where i could add the server URL and handling the response . thanks

Comment: Well, you were asking about "creating Java Server to handle Client requests and respond to it" -- but you couldn't use raw sockets. The Simple Framework allows you to embed an HTTP webserver within your application. So, the example above isn't about connecting to a remote server, but about allowing clients to connect to you (as your question seems to imply.) To be clear, I'm not sure how it would integrate with Google App engine.